# How to create and redeem coupons in Recurly, programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal, recurly

++++++++++++++

Actual Scenario: I am working on a site (ASP.Net using C#) where the system will have 3 different subscription plans i.e. monthly, quarterly and yearly. All the subscription plans have their own cost and pricing. Now, if the system/admin wants to give any discounts to any subscribed user (regardless of subscription plan) on their on-going subscription based on some business logic (for example, for some user it may be $4 and for other it may be $25). How can I achieve this goal. I tried PayPal and Recurly, but stuck in-between.

++++++++++++++

I have to create a coupon and redeem the same using Recurly dynamically in C#. But, as per the code mentioned in "https://docs.recurly.com/api/v1/subscription-plans", we have to use Recurly API v2, but we don't have the code to create and redeem the coupon. So, please help me on how can I create coupons and redeem the same.

When we are using below code in mentioned URL "[Recurly PUT request working but returning server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738923/recurly-put-request-working-but-returning-server-error)", it causes error while getting response.

```
uri = "https://" + subdomain + ".recurly.com/v2/subscriptions/" + uuid + "/reactivate";

try
{
    string xml = "<subscription><timeframe>now</timeframe></subscription>"; //also tried with blank string.
    byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
    HttpWebRequest renewRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    renewRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeB64);
    renewRequest.Method = "PUT";
    renewRequest.ContentType = "text/XML";
    renewRequest.ContentLength = arr.Length;

    Stream datastream = renewRequest.GetRequestStream();
    datastream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    datastream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse renewResponse = (HttpWebResponse)renewRequest.GetResponse();

}
```

Looking for kind response and help...

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do ?

Comment: As I have mentioned above i.e. I am working on a site (ASP.Net using C#) where the system will have 3 different subscription plans i.e. monthly, quarterly and yearly. All the subscription plans have their own cost and pricing. Now, if the system/admin wants to give any discounts to any subscribed user (regardless of subscription plan) on their on-going subscription based on some business logic (for example, for some user it may be $4 and for other it may be $25). How can I achieve this goal. How User can avail discounts on on-going subscription without affecting current subscription...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ([recurly.com](http://recurly.com/)) just made available a [release candidate of an all new API client for C#](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc1) compatible with [Recurly APIv2](http://docs.recurly.com/api) that we highly recommend using. The client API is stable and this release will shortly become the final release pending new show-stopping bugs.

Here's how to [get started using it](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/tree/v2#recurly-net-client).

Be sure [set up your configuration](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/tree/v2#configuration).

Here's how to [create a coupon](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/blob/v2/examples.md#coupons).

Here's how to [redeem coupons](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/blob/v2/examples.md#coupon-redemptions).

More examples are [available here](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-net/blob/v2/examples.md).

If you have further questions please don't hesitate to ask our support team! support@recurly.com.